# Ubuntu 12.10 AMD64, can't update

Tags: updates, 12.10

I am getting this error message when trying to update.

```
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
W:Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/commercial-ppa-uploaders/skype/ubuntu/dists/quantal/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.92.191 80]
E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

And this error halts the updating process, so it never updates.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Solved:

In Software Sources, label Other Software, there was a repository called "Canonical Partners Added by Software Center main". I unticked this option because still there is another source called "Canonical Partners Software Packaged by Canonical for their partners".

I also changed to USA server (I was in main), as I have seen that it seems to have some to do with Skype repository in the main server.

This seems to have solved the problem.